# How to create a function to create bin for all columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: binning

I have a pandas data frame that contains 30 columns named as age, salary, investments, loan etc. I have converted all numeric values to standardised values using sklean standard Scalar. Hence, all 30 columns contain standardised values. Now, I need to create three bins naming "low", "medium", "high". I have tried to create bins, manually by writing coding for each column. The code I have used is

`bins = [-3,-1.5,1,3]`

`names=["low","med","high"]`

`df['age'] = pd.cut(df['age'], bins, labels=names)`

It is working, but I need to write code for all 30 columns. I am not sure, how to create dynamic code to create bins for all 30 columns.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will apply on all columns

```
bins = [-3,-1.5,1,3]

names=["low","med","high"]

df = pd.DataFrame([[-1,0,-2,-1,-2,1,0], [-1,0,-2,-2,-2,-1,1]])

df.apply(pd.cut, bins=bins, labels=names)
```